# MYsql Join on int to varchar ( not working as expected)

Tags: mysql, join, type-conversion

```
select  b.*, a.id_order 
FROM trans a 
INNER JOIN shipment b
   ON a.id_order = b.trans_order_id
```

Even though both the columns are having different values, It is still joining that row.
For Example below is the weird combination 
 `trans_order_id= "6229582 8481 AB"` and `id_order ='6229582'`
Both the values are not same but still MySQL is getting them Joined

Both the columns are having different datatypes

```
b.trans_order_id  varchar(45)
a.id_order int(10)
```

I tried Cast,  convert ( No Use)

Please help me in letting me know if there is any solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: well `"6229582 8481 AB"` is diferent to `'6229582'`. Do you want he join to the first number before the space?

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` for your tables  Because if you are trying to join and integer with a varchar, then you have some bigger issues there.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of: `DESCRIBE trans;` and `DESCRIBE shipment;` in order to know the type of `id_order` and `trans_order_id`.

Comment: I'm also having this same issue when making JOIN on int with varchar columns. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's MySql for you :/

My guess is `trans.id_order` has a number type of some kind, and MySql is silently converting `shipment.trans_order_id` from a string type to the number type for the join compare.

Pretty much no database other than MySql would try this, and I believe the default behavior for *new installations* post-5.7 would also handle this better, but even if you're running the latest 8.01 you'll see this if the database was original installed and then upgraded from a version prior to 5.7.

You might be able to avoid this by instead explicitly casting `a.id_order` to a whatever varchar type you use in for `shipment.trans_order_id`, so that MySql doesn't coerce the wrong side of the expression.

It also looks like you might have a poor schema design on the `shipment` table, where you're trying to put multiple values into a single column.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the question. OP is saying mySql is join those rows even when they are different?

Comment: That's my understanding. I believe the OP is saying he _is currently_ seeing these rows in his results, does not want to see them. However, the English is broken enough that the opposite interpretation is also possible... that he currently does not match these rows, and he wants to know how to do so.

Comment: I am currently using 5.6 and may need to switch to  5.7 and check if this feature can be handled better.  Thanks guys for answering  and sorry for  the confusion